# Is it possible to stream a file from a Java server to OpenStack Swift?

Tags: java, api, openstack, openstack-swift, jclouds

I need to store very large files in the OpenStack swift through the Java server. Java server performs authentication, validation and other special logic after that it sends file into OpenStack Swift.

The problem is that I don't need to store big files localy on the Java server. I don't need them there. So, Java server has to act like a pipe. It has to accept an input stream from the client and create an output stream to the OpenStack Swift Proxy after that it has to read small parts of data from the input stream and send them to the output stream.

Are there any APIs which let us create such a Java server?

Answer (score 1):

jclouds has support for Swift

https://jclouds.apache.org/

Comment: Does it support a file stream into OpenStack Swift without keeping an entire file in the RAM or on the disk? I haven't found any information about it.

Comment: You might be able to do that. Swift supports multi-part uploads, so based on how a Java server handles the file upload, it should be possible.